# Annotations from javax.validation.constraints in combination with custom ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring, validation, constraints, bean-validation

I have a problem to combine the javax annotation with custom ConstraintValidators.

I have an example class Person, where the name and the age are required.

```
@PersonConstraint
public class Person {

     @NotNull
     private String name;
     @NotNull
     private Integer age;     
     ...
}
```

And I have an additional constraint:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = PersonValidator.class)
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PersonConstraint{

    String message() default  "...";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

For the custom Validator:

```
public class PersonValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PersonConstraint, Person> {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Person value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(value.getAge() < 18) 
            return false;
        ...
    }
}
```

When a Person object is validated now and the age is null, I got a Nullpointer Exception in the PersonValidator. I thoguht, this is something, which is checked by the javax Annoation @NotNull. 
Is there a solution to combine the annotations with the custom validators or do I have to check the null values in the validor by myself?

(The code is just an example - but this is a general question)

Comment: you mean to say, that you need to control the order of validation right?

Comment: Yes. That was my intention.

Comment: it is not the right answer, but to make the things simple, you can validate the null check here in `PersonValidator` class itself right?

Comment: this would be the simplest way, yes. But i think its not correct. There must be a common solution for this problem.

Comment: Agreed, You should probably look into `group` I guess.
`@GroupSequence ({Person.class, PersonValidator.class})`
For more refer : http://mrbool.com/knowing-the-hibernate-validator-part-2/21878

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are working with the group and group sequences, there is no guaranteed order in which constraints are going to be evaluated. You cannot rely in your custom constraint that the `@NotNull` already has occured. And even it it had you would still get a `NullPointerException`. Bean Validation will per default not stop after the first constraint violation, but collect all violations of a required validation (hence a set of `ConstraintViolation`s are returned. So there might actually be already a constraint violation for `age`, but in your custom `ConstraintValidator` you would still be accessing a `null` value. You cannot get around doing a `null` check at this stage.